# How to define different get functions according to the number of path elements in Python Tornado?

Tags: python, tornado

For example, I define two path in the rulelist:

```
("/application", app),
("/application/display/(\d+)", app)
```

And in my app class, I want to define two get functions separately for different paths:

```
def get(self):
    self.write("display app list")

def get(self, action, id):
    self.write("display app info by id")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create two methods by the same name, Python will always call the second one. This is how Python works.

But you can create one single `get` method with default parameters:

Example:

```
def get(self, action=None, id=None):
    if action != None and id != None:
        # do something ...
    else:
        # do something else ...
```